# Specific magic weapon Shatterspike confusion

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I am confused about how the specific magic weapon [Shatterspike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/shatterspike) is worded.

> This intimidating weapon appears to be a longsword with multiple hooks, barbs, and serrations along the blade, excellent for catching and sundering a foe’s weapon. Wielders without the Improved Sunder feat use a shatterspike as a +1 longsword only. Wielders with the Improved Sunder feat instead use shatterspike as a +4 longsword when attempting to sunder an opponent’s weapon. Shatterspike can damage weapons with an enhancement bonus of +4 or lower.

Its the last line "Shatterspike can damage weapons with an enhancement bonus of +4 or lower" that has me confused. I know in the original pathfinder rules that a +1 weapon was unable to damage weapons or armor with a higher enhancement bonus, but that was changed at some point to enhancement bonuses increase hit-points and hardness. In any case, the wording here doesn't make sense to me. Under either rules a +4 weapon would be able to damage other +4 or lower weapons, so why call it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules are often repeated when relevant, particularly obscure ones like this. In all likelihood, it was solely meant as a reminder of this rule when it existed, and possibly to prevent anyone from arguing that “using” it “as a +4” didn’t mean it *was* a +4 and so it still couldn’t damage those weapons.¹

As it was probably just reminder text/confirmation that *shatterspike* really works like a +4 when sundering, yes even that way, we should probably not read anything more into it than that, and update *shatterspike* along with the rest of the rules about sundering magic weapons.

1. <sub>One might wonder how you use a weapon “as a” +*anything* in that case, though, since the use of such weapons is identical to those with lesser magic, and indeed to non-magical weapons. But I never said it would be a *good* argument, only that people might make it. Cutting such things off at the pass is often necessary in rules-writing.</sub>